# Can MVC 3 and WebForms co-exist on a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a website which has a WebForms 4 site.  This website is www.mysite.co.uk and I'm currently developing a microsite using MVC 3 which I want to upload to the same site, but under a different directory.  Is this possible or do I need to create a new website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is possible, this article might be able to help.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Another article from Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx